# How to receive values in js function from html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am fetching some data from database in html using php. I need to pass the key to js function but I am not able to do.

I need to pass `field_id` to `updateRecords()` js function using `onClick()` function of html button in the code below. How can I do that?

Before, I was using same code to send value to directly php. that was bit straight forward. Now to implement ajax, I need to go through js that has stuck me in this code. I tried different solutions but no success so far.

Here is my code:

**html/php:**

```
<?php
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT field_id, description, corner_points, notes FROM fields");
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
        ?>
          <tr>
                <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['field_id'] ?></td>
                <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['description'] ?></td>
                <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['corner_points'] ?></td>
                <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['notes'] ?></td>
                <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="submit2" type="submit" onclick="updateRecords()">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
```

**Here is receiving js:**

```
function updateRecords(field_id) {
    // get values
    //var field_id = $("#field_id").val();

    // Update the details by requesting to the server using ajax
    $.post("ajax/edit-field.php", {
            field_id: field_id,

        },
        function readRecords (data, status) {
            // reload Users by using readRecords();
            readRecords();
        }
    );
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried this way too `(mentioned in answer1)` but it didn't succeed. By didn't succeed I mean I was getting error, `' Notice: Undefined variable: field_id in C:\ajax\edit-field.php on line 43 '.`

This is the code I am using in edit-field.php to receive the field_id from js. Can you see it plz.

**edit-field.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET["field_id"])) //used too if(isset($_POST["field_id"]))       
      {
       $field_id = $_GET["field_id"]; // same here with same results
    }
     try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT field_id, description, corner_points, damming_level_distance_map, pipeline_distance_map, notes FROM fields where field_id = $field_id");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row)
            { }
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
            exit('<b>Catched exception at line '. $e->getLine() .' (code : '. $e->getCode() .') :</b> '. $e->getMessage());
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: `onclick="updateRecords('<?= $row['field_id'] ?>')"` …?

Comment: onclick="updateRecords('<?= $row['field_id'] ?>')"

Answer (score 2):

You method signature is looking for the field_id as argument, but you never print it in the html, while generating it server side, change the following line:

```
        <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="submit2" type="submit" onclick="updateRecords()">Edit</button></td>
```

to

```
    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="submit2" type="submit" onclick="updateRecords(<?= $row['field_id'] ?>)">Edit</button></td>
```

Keep in mind that if your field_id is not a number but a string you have to enclose it in quotes to avoid throwing a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you plz see the edit that's a reply to your naswer. It's bit long to fit here in reply.

Comment: @XCeptable you are using `$_GET` against a post method.